# What can I use to archive files, that anyone would be able to open?

Tags: archiving

I have files that I need to send to several different international locations.  They're confidential files, so I need them to be password protected.  Therefore, I was putting the files on a CD and mailing them to the different locations.  I had used iZarc, so I could password protect them.  Some of the locations weren't able to open the CDs.  Some were getting a message "can not open output file".  Many of these places are hospitals.

One of the doctors had said it's due to the firewalls and anti-virus there. Now, I'm being asked (by my work) to send flash drives to the ones that couldn't open the CDs.  How can I do this and be sure that they'll be able to open them?  Also, how do I put a password on them?  I'm assuming they have a problem with opening iZarc, so I can't use that?  How else can I do it?

These are medical records on PDF, and they probably don't require compression. I think they would fit fine on the flash drive, without compressing. I only need to put a password on them, so it couldn't be accessed by someone if it got lost in the mail.

I'll also add that I'm not an IT person, and feel this task is a little bit above my head, but I don't want to admit that and give up on it. :)

We do have an IT department here, but I was asked to do the task. I know that IT stays very busy, so it's probably better if I do it. It won't be so bad, once I figure it all out. It helps that I'm fairly good at research, which landed me here.

Comment: zip files can be password protected. Its not particularly strong tho.

Comment: password protecting pdfs might be an option. I'd note there's VERY specific security protocols for medical information. I wouldn't talk to IT cause I didn't know how to do it. I'd talk to IT cause messing it up would be terrible for your organisation.

Comment: The names of people aren't on the documents.  It's medical information from drug research, but yes, there is very specific security protocol.  I've decided I'll just password protect the flash drive itself, and not archive the files.  I asked a colleague and he walked me through it a bit.